# Why Visual Studio 2013 publish website with source code?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-deployment, publishing

I'm using `Visual Studio 2013`. And have created new `website`. When i `publish` this `website` using `publish dialog` it publish website with `sourcecode` and doesnt merge into `dll` When published, in theory it should compile all the code into an single assembly.

**So, how to `publish` website containing `binary files` and not the `sourceCode` of the website in `Visual Studio 2013`**

Help Appreciated!

Comment: please give the reason why its DOWNVOTED? If you dont know the answer "LEAVE IT" but do not go on Down Voting...

Answer (score 0):

in first ----> create **backup** from your project

1. create new project '**File** -> **New** -> **Project** ...' and select **Web** Folder in VB or c# and select **Asp.Net Empty Web Application**
2. **Copy All** Files & Folder in root from old project by windows explorer
3. into new project **right click** on your **WebApplication Project** and select **paste**
4. Edit **Refrences** tab in new project and **add** your **assemply**
5. **Build project**

if **no error**  into publish wizard

1. connection tab: select 'File system' method and select target path in local computer than you compile and export finale project output
2. setting tab: select 'Release' or 'Debug' config and in File publish option checked 'Delete all exiting...' , 'Exclude files...'
3. push 'Publish' button

goto target path in local computer ---> without source code 'cs file'

Comment: hi @Ali H.A i have followed your steps but i am not able to find the "Release" option their is only "Debug" option in the dropdownlist! proceeding with your said steps it still shows the "sourceCode" in published folder.. :(

Comment: hi, if you create web project with 'file->new->web project' publish method send source files into target site
by this method of create project 'File -> New -> Project ...-> web', you can publish web without source files,with compile assemply

Comment: i have used File->New Website for creating new website...So, do u have any idea for WEBSITE publish without source code?

Comment: no, i don't idea 
but your method for creating new website and my method are the same way in 'code, compile,...' website